# React native expo error. Undefined is not an object(evaluating item.basicData.criminalName)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-context

```
const SearchContext = React.createContext();
class SearchProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    tfG: false,
    aboutToSearch: "criminals",
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SearchContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          changeAboutToSearch: (value) => {
            if (value == true) {
              console.log(value);
              this.setState({ aboutToSearch: "gangNames", tfG: true });
            } else {
              this.setState({ aboutToSearch: "criminals", tfG: false });
            }
          },
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </SearchContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
class SearchBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SearchContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => (
          <>
            <View
              style={{
                marginTop: 30,
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <View>
                  <Text>{context.state.tfG ? "Gangs" : "Criminals"}</Text>
                  <Switch
                    onValueChange={context.changeAboutToSearch}
                    value={context.state.tfG}
                  />
                </View>
                <Item rounded style={{ width: "65%" }}>
                  <Label style={{ textAlign: "right", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                    <AntDesign name="search1" size={24} color="black" />
                  </Label>
                  <Input
                    onChangeText={(query) => {
                      this.props.refine(query);
                    }}
                    placeholder={"Search Criminals/Gangs"}
                    placeholderTextColor={"black"}
                    clearButtonMode={"always"}
                    clearButtonMode={"always"}
                    spellCheck={false}
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize={"none"}
                  />
                </Item>
              </View>
            </View>
          </>
        )}
      </SearchContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
const ConnectedSearchBox = connectSearchBox(SearchBox);
class InfiniteHits extends Component {
  onEndReached = () => {
    if (this.props.hasMore) {
      this.props.refine();
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <SearchContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => (
          <>
            <FlatList
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  {context.state.tfG ? (
                    
                      
                            <Text>{item.addGang}</Text>
                          
                  ) : (
                
                     
                            <Text>{item.basicData.criminalName}</Text>
                    
                  )}
              )}
              data={this.props.hits}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.objectID}
              onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </SearchContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
const ConnectedInfiniteHits = connectInfiniteHits(InfiniteHits);
export default class InitialDb extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Gangs: "",
      criminals: "",
      loading: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const searchClient = algoliasearch(
      "asdf",
      "asdf"
    );
    return (
      <SearchProvider>
        <SearchContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <>
              <SafeAreaView>
                <BackButton />
                <View>
                  <InstantSearch
                    searchClient={searchClient}
                    indexName={context.state.aboutToSearch}
                  >
                    <ConnectedSearchBox />
                    <ConnectedInfiniteHits />
                  </InstantSearch>
                </View>
              </SafeAreaView>
            </>
          )}
        </SearchContext.Consumer>
      </SearchProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

**In The above code, in SearchProvider class, I'm using it as context provider class(Context API), and SearchBox class, I'm using it to search algolia search, and in InfiniteHits class I am using it as to show the results. And in InitialDb class I'm rendering everything.Here I have 2 collections in my algolia indeces which has different type of objects(gangNames and criminals). And I want to populate it based on the switch on or Off. If it is on then gangNames Index object should populate and if it is off then criminals index should populate. By default it is Off(false/criminals index will populate), and If I switch it on(true) then I'm getting the gangNames Index, But if I toggle it again Off(false for criminals Index), then I'm getting "Undefined is not an object error"**
[Here Im attaching the screenshot, This is the error what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4kjl.png)

Comment: You should not format the text in bold. Bold should be used for highlighting certain things, not all the text.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `item.basicData` is not an object and you are trying to access property of a non-object. You may try to use: `item.basicData && item.basicData.criminals` or if it is available `item.basicData?.criminals`.